# In Mongodb aggregation, how can I return all documents containing an array value whose second element exists?

Tags: mongodb

I have Mongodb documents which have an array value. I want to return all documents where the array value has a second element. How can I do that?

```
example document :

{
 _id : "672d75267",
 name : "somename",
 arr : [1,2,3]
}


db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $match : {
      $expr : {
        $arrayElemAt : ["$arr",2]
     }
   }
 }
])
```

Comment: Query seems fine as per your question. Remember indexes start at 0. So index=2 would be value "3" in the arr.

Answer (score 0):

**Array index start from 0 that is why we have taken "arr.1"**

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "arr.1": {
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  },
])
```